# Reactjs hide and unhide all records on a Toggle button Click

Tags: reactjs

**Reactjs** hide and unhide all records on a Toggle button Click

I have three records in the array. I need to hide and unhide each records seperately when a Toggle button is click.

**My problem is that each time a particular Toggle button is clicked, instead of hiding and Unhide just that records, it will
hide and unhide all the three records.**

I guess I need to set an `{post.id}` for each **Toggle Button**. can someone help me with that

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class AutoButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      shown: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", title: "my first title" },
        { id: "2", title: "my second title"},
        { id: "3", title: "my third title" }
      ]
    });
  }


toggle() {
        this.setState({
            shown: !this.state.shown
        });
    }


  render() {

var shown = {
            display: this.state.shown ? "block" : "none"
        };

        var hidden = {
            display: this.state.shown ? "none" : "block"
        }





  return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
<h2 style={ shown }> {post.title} --{post.id} 

</h2>

<button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Toggle</button>


                <br />

              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, is to add a flag to each item in your data, and then toggle that flag :

```
class AutoButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      shown: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", title: "my first title", visible: true },
        { id: "2", title: "my second title", visible: true },
        { id: "3", title: "my third title", visible: true }
      ]
    });
  }


  toggle(id) {
    const newData = this.state.data.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, visible: !item.visible};
      }

      return item;
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                <h2 style={{ display: post.visible ? "block" : "none"}}> {post.title} --{post.id} </h2>
                <button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, post.id)}>Toggle</button>
                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Edit

Another way, is to keep track of the hidden items, something like this :

```
class AutoButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      shown: true,
      hiddenItems: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", title: "my first title" },
        { id: "2", title: "my second title" },
        { id: "3", title: "my third title" }
      ]
    });
  }


  toggle(id) {

    if(this.isHidden(id)) {
      const newHiddenItems = this.state.hiddenItems.filter(item => item !== id);
      this.setState({
        hiddenItems: newHiddenItems
       });
    } else {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        hiddenItems: state.hiddenItems.concat(id)
      }));
    }
  }

  isHidden(id) {
    return this.state.hiddenItems.includes(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                <h2 style={{ display: this.isHidden(post.id) ? "none" : "block"}}> {post.title} --{post.id} </h2>
                <button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, post.id)}>Toggle</button>
                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response so far Sir Mohamed. My concern is that you set visibility to true inside an array. what if I have one million records in the database which generates such an array, it will make my database design look some how. Between thanks for response so far

Comment: Thank you so  much